# Linear Operators: Continuous $\Rightarrow$ Bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $T:V\rightarrow V'$ be a continuous linear operator between two normed vector spaces $V,V'$.
Show that it is bounded.
Continuity is defined as $\lim_{n}\|x_n-x\|=0\Rightarrow \lim_n\|T(x_n-x)\|=0$.
Boundedeness is defined as: $\exists M\geq0$ s.t. $\|T(x)\|\leq M\|x\|\ \forall x\in V$.

Proof:
Let $T$ be continuous. Assume by contradiction that $\nexists M\geq1 $ s.t. $\left\| T(x)\right\|\leq M\| x\| \ \forall x\in V$. Then there exists a sequence $\{x_n \}_{n\geq 1}\in V$ such that $\left\| T(x_n)\right\|> n\| x_n\| \ \forall x_n\in V$, and so
$$
1<\frac{1}{n\|x_n\|}\|T(x_n)\|=\left\| T\left(\frac{x_n}{n\|x_n\|}\right)\right\|\ \ \forall x_n.
$$
But $\left\|\frac{x_n}{n\|x_n\|}\right\|\rightarrow \|0\|=0\ \text{as }n\rightarrow \infty$, and so by continuity at $0$
$$
\left\| T\left(\frac{x_n}{n\|x_n\|}-0\right)\right\|\rightarrow\left\| T\left(0\right)\right\|=\|0\|=0,
$$
which is a contradiciton.

Is it correct?

Comment: It might look better if you start with something like.... Given any $M>0$ there exists $x$ such that $||T(x)||\geq M ||x||$...

Comment: I guess he mean just bounded...

Comment: Do you really need that $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence?

Comment: you can not pick such $x_n$.. there exists some $x_n$ and  you just have to take it....

Comment: Please stop editing your question continuously, rather spend sometime to respond for the comments.....

Comment: You can hardly have $\left\| T(x_n)\right\|> n\| x_n\| \ \forall x_n\in V$. Other than your apparent problem with understanding the meaning of quantifiers (which could be alleviated by either  forgoing them altogether and just spelling things out, or going back to learn some basics instead of analysis), it seems more or less fine.

Comment: It sounds to me the same to say that there exists a sequence such that $\|T(x_n)\| >n\| x_n\|$ and there exists a sequence such that $\|T(x_n)\| >n\| x_n\|\ \forall x_n\in V$

Comment: It is not same.... It is not "for all"...